# ActiveReports v11 Dynamic Layout

Tags: vb.net, activereports

I've created a process by which users can dynamically add data input fields to data input screens.  Works just fine, I am able to capture data, store it in the database, and retrieve the data.  No problem.  Now I need to report out the data in a report.  We use ActiveReports v11, I found an example that creates a report layout dynamically [here](http://help.grapecity.com/activereports/webhelp/Legacy/ActiveReports6/topic111.html).  Of course I had to modify the code to fit my circumstances.  When I run the report I always get 4 label and textboxes pairs for the second record in the employee dataset, no idea why and I (apparently) can't see anything wrong with my code.  I've confirmed that the data table has 1 row with 3 columns for each iteration of the report, yet no matter what I do I get a duplicate of the 1st label/textbox pair in the report output.  Perhaps another pair of eyes can see what I cannot.  The report code:

```
Imports GrapeCity.ActiveReports.SectionReportModel
Imports System.Drawing

Public Class AdditionalData
    Public Property  As String = ""
    Private m_arrayFields As ArrayList
    Private MylabelFont As Font = New Font("Arial", 12)
    Private MyTextFont As Font = New Font("Arial", 12)
    'Create an array to hold the fields defined by the user
    Public WriteOnly Property LabelList() As ArrayList
        Set(ByVal Value As ArrayList)
            m_arrayFields = Value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private Top As Single = 0.9F 'Place the first label/textbox pair under the report title
    Private Left As Single = 0.967F 'Left margin
    Private m_defaultHeight As Single = 0.25F
    Private m_defaultWidth As Single = 4.0F
    'Set up report formatting and add label/textbox pairs based on user definition
    Private Sub constructReport()
        Try
            Me.Detail.CanGrow = True
            Me.Detail.CanShrink = True
            Me.Detail.KeepTogether = True
            Dim i As Integer
            For i = 0 To m_arrayFields.Count - 1
                'For all fields defined by the user create a label and a textbox
                Dim lbl As New Label
                lbl.ForeColor = Color.Blue
                lbl.Font = MylabelFont
                'Set the label to display the name of the defined field
                lbl.Text = m_arrayFields(i) + ":"
                'Set the location of each label
                lbl.Top = Top
                lbl.Left = Left
                lbl.Width = 0.9F
                lbl.Height = m_defaultHeight
                Me.Detail.Controls.Add(lbl)

                Dim txt As New GrapeCity.ActiveReports.SectionReportModel.TextBox
                'Set the textbox to display data
                txt.DataField = m_arrayFields(i)
                txt.ForeColor = Color.Black
                txt.Font = MyTextFont
                'Set the location of the textbox
                txt.Top = Top
                txt.Left = Left + 1.0F
                txt.Width = m_defaultWidth
                txt.Height = m_defaultHeight
                Me.Detail.Controls.Add(txt)
                'Increment the vertical location by adding the height of the added controls
                Top = Top + m_defaultHeight
            Next
            Label_name.Text = EmployeeName
        Catch ex As Exception
            LogError("Code File:AdditionalData.vb/constructReport - ERROR: An error occurred formatting the reports layout, the error is: " & ex.Message & Chr(10) & "Trace:" & Chr(10) & GetExceptionInfo(ex))
        End Try
    End Sub
    Private Sub AdditionalData_ReportStart(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.ReportStart
        constructReport()
    End Sub
End Class
```

The report layout and data table is created by this code:

```
Dim Additionalreport As New AdditionalData
If Department.HasAdditionalData = 1 Then
    AdditionalData = GetAdditionalDataFields(MyConnection)
    AdditionalDataTable = New DataTable
    If AdditionalData.Tables(0).Rows.Count > 0 Then
        ' The department defined data they want to collect and report out
        Dim Labels As New ArrayList
        For Each MyDataRow3 As DataRow In AdditionalData.Tables(0).Rows
            Labels.Add(MyDataRow3("Title"))
            AdditionalDataTable.Columns.Add(MyDataRow3("Title"))
        Next
        Additionalreport.LabelList = Labels
    End If
```

The report is executed by the following code:

```
    For Each MyDataRow2 In MyDataSet.Tables(0).Rows
        If Department.HasAdditionalData = 1 Then 'If additional data is defined, run report
            AdditionalDataTable.Clear()
            AdditionalDataTable.AcceptChanges()
            Dim myRow As DataRow
            Dim DataFieldColumnName As String = ""
            AdditionalDataValues = GetAdditionalDataFieldData(MyConnection, MyDataRow2("EmployeeID"))
            'lets populate the table for the reports data source
            ' First add a row to the datatable
            myRow = AdditionalDataTable.NewRow
            For Each MyDataRow5 As DataRow In AdditionalDataValues.Tables(0).Rows
                DataFieldColumnName = GetDataFieldTitle(MyConnection, MyDataRow5("DataFieldkey"))
                myRow(DataFieldName) = MyDataRow5("DataFieldValue")
            Next
            AdditionalDataTable.Rows.Add(myRow)
            Additionalreport.EmployeeName = MyDataRow2("FirstName") & " " & MyDataRow2("LastName")
            Additionalreport.DataSource = AdditionalDataTable
            Additionalreport.Run()
            rpt.Document.Pages.AddRange(Additionalreport.Document.Pages)
        End If
    Next
```

The employee data is contained in a dataset passed into the CompileAdditionalDataReport sub.  The report is run for each record in the data set table.  Debug code shows that each record created in AdditionalDataTable has 3 columns and 1 row of data, yet when the report is run, the second run always produces 4 label/textbox pairs with the first label/textbox pair duplicated on the last line in the report.  The data displayed is always correct, just can't understand why the second run has 4 label/textbox pairs displayed as only 3 are defined.  Can anyone see what's causing this to happen, I obviously can't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently the second time the report was run, an artifact from the first run existed on the second run, still don't where the artifact came from and how it remained, but it's there.  I changed my code to generate a new copy of the report layout each time it's run and the phantom output disappeared.  I created a function that creates the layout and returns the data table via a reference variable and a new copy of the report, my code:

```
Public Function GenerateAdditionalDataReport(ByRef pAdditionalDatatable As DataTable) As AdditionalData
    Dim AdditionalData As New DataSet
    Dim AdditionalDataValues As New DataSet
    Dim AdditionalDataTable As New DataTable
    Dim Additionalreport As New AdditionalData
    Dim MyLeagueInfo As New AssociationInformation
    Dim MyConnection As OracleConnection = OpenConnection(Current.Session("USERNAME"), Current.Session("PASSWORD"))
    Dim MyRegOptions As New DataSet
    Department = Current.Session("DepartmentInfo")
    If MyLeagueInfo.HasAdditionalData = 1 Then
        AdditionalData = GetAdditionalDataFields(MyConnection)
        AdditionalDataTable = New DataTable
        If AdditionalData.Tables(0).Rows.Count > 0 Then
            ' They collect their own data
            Dim Labels As New ArrayList
            For Each MyDataRow3 As DataRow In AdditionalData.Tables(0).Rows
                Labels.Add(MyDataRow3("Title"))
                AdditionalDataTable.Columns.Add(MyDataRow3("Title"))
            Next
            Additionalreport.LabelList = Labels
        End If
    End If
    pAdditionalDatatable = AdditionalDataTable
    MyConnection.Close()
    MyConnection.Dispose()
    MyConnection = Nothing
    Return Additionalreport
End Function
```

Then I run the report for each person in the dataset:

```
        If Department.HasAdditionalData = 1 Then
            Additionalreport = GenerateAdditionalDataReport(AdditionalDataTable)
            Dim myRow As DataRow
            Dim DataFieldName As String = ""
            AdditionalDataValues = GetAdditionalDataFieldData(MyConnection, MyDataRow2("EmployeeID"))
            ' lets populate the table for the reports datasource
            ' First create a new row to the datatable
            myRow = AdditionalDataTable.NewRow
            For Each MyDataRow5 As DataRow In AdditionalDataValues.Tables(0).Rows
                DataFieldName = GetDataFieldTitle(MyConnection, MyDataRow5("DataFieldkey"))
                 myRow(DataFieldName) = MyDataRow5("DataFieldValue")
            Next
            AdditionalDataTable.Rows.Add(myRow)
            Additionalreport.EmployeeName = MyDataRow2("FirstName") & " " & MyDataRow2("LastName")
            Additionalreport.DataSource = AdditionalDataTable
            Additionalreport.Run()
            rpt.Document.Pages.AddRange(Additionalreport.Document.Pages)
        End If
    Next
```